# What is the mathematical meaning of split0_test_score in "cv_results_" attribute of GridSearchCV in sklearn.model_selection

Tags: scikit-learn, auto-sklearn

I am trying to understand the meaning of GridSearchCV attributes, can someone help me understand the mathematical representation of "split0_test_score'?